# how can i put widget above the sliver app bar like this pic

Tags: flutter, uitableview, user-interface, flutter-layout

[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kijhv.jpg)

any idea for this problem
I tried to put stack but didn't work
I could have put everything in a sliver list and do it with stack and containers
but I need when I scroll the app bar disappear

Comment: can you describe more specifically?you want to add a sticky screen above sliverapp bar?

Comment: what widget exactly you want to add ??

Comment: @xahid_rocks 
this container with the border-radius
to make exactly the same UI as the picture above

Comment: @MichaelSoliman
this container with the border-radius
to make exactly the same UI as the picture above

Comment: If the answer is not what you're looking for please let me know

Comment: @MichaelSoliman yes it's not 
this code is right but I need the animation for the sliver list 
if I remove  pinned: false,
the animation come back but the UI become so bad because of the container

Comment: i don't fully understand you, if you can clarify more what do you want to do would be great!

Comment: @MichaelSoliman I am sorry for the too much qs

if u try to scroll up down its const
no animation 
try to remove  pinned: false,
and add a sliver list 
u will get an animation when u scroll up or down that's all I need

and I appreciate everything you did
I hope that I clarified the problem to you

Comment: @MichaelSoliman

look at the beginning of this video from s18

Comment: where is the video?

Comment: @MichaelSoliman 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUXGNGJs-Qk&t=18s&ab_channel=Himdevedevelopment

Answer (score 0):

So you have two options, first and that is the one i wrote the next example with, is that your `SliverAppBar` consists of a `Stack` that a have both the image and the movie title container which will be the same color as the body so it appears as one container ((bordered with green color to illustrate)). This will make the appbar disappear like you want i guess.
Second option is that you don't use an appbar and the page will consist of just a body which will be a large `Container` and you'll do the same with stack like above.

I hope that this is what you're looking for.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            primary: true,
            pinned: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
              background: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.green)),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstATop),
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDg3MmI1ZDYtMDZjYi00ZWRlLTk4NzEtZjY4Y2U0NjE5YmRiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzAxMjE1NDg@._V1_UY1200_CR92,0,630,1200_AL_.jpg"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Gangs of New York",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                    shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                    child: Text("Action"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 5),
                                Container(
                                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                    shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                    child: Text("etc"),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline, color: Colors.white, size: 50),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: 700,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text("body"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
   }
```

[image]